# Inline `after_commit` Callbacks in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a sidekiq job that needs to be run after the commit, but only in some situations and not all, in order to avoid [a common race condition](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#writing-thread-safe-code).

For example, the below `after_commit` will always fire but the code inside will only execute if the flag is true (previously set in the verify method).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  after_commit do |user|
    if @enqueue_some_job
      SomeJob.new(user).enqueue
      @enqueue_some_job = nil
    end
  end

  def verify
    @enqueue_some_job = ...
    ...
    save!
  end
end
```

The code is a bit ugly. I'd much rather be able to somehow wrap the callback inline like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def verify
    if ...
      run_after_commit do |user|
        SomeJob.new(user).enqueue
      end
    end
    ...
    save!
  end
end
```

Does anything built into Rails exist to support a syntax like this (that doesn't rely on setting a temporary instance variable)? Or do any libraries exist that extend Rails to add a syntax like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution using a via a concern. The snippet gets reused enough that it is probably a better option to abstract the instance variable and form a reusable pattern. It doesn't handle returns (not sure which are supported via `after_commit` since no transaction is present to roll back.

**app/models/concerns/callbackable.rb**

```
module Callbackable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do

    after_commit do |resource|
      if @_execute_after_commit
        @_execute_after_commit.each do |callback|
          callback.call(resource)
        end
        @_execute_after_commit = nil
      end
    end
  end

  def execute_after_commit(&callback)
    if callback
      @_execute_after_commit ||= []
      @_execute_after_commit << callback
    end
  end

end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Callbackable

  def verify
    if ...
      execute_after_commit do |user|
        SomeJob.new(user).enqueue
      end
    end
    ...
    save!
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method name instead of a block when declaring callbacks:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :do_something!

  def do_something!
  end
end
```

To set a condition on the callback you can use the `if` and `unless` options. Note that these are just hash options - not keywords.

You can use a method name or a lambda:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :do_something!, if: -> { self.some_value > 2 }
  after_commit :do_something!, unless: :something?

  def do_something!
  end

  def something?
    true || false
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks max - unfortunately the conditions for the check live inside the function (in the same case `verify`) - so I'd then need to set instance variables for each of those .

Comment: Either I don't really understand what you are trying to get at or you are really overthinking it. You could use your `verify` method directly in the if clause or an `if` option - I can't really see why you think you need instance variables / state and not just a method that evaluates to a boolean condition.

Comment: You also seem to somewhat confused as to when the code runs - callbacks are declared when the class is evaluated. Your verify method in the second example is an instance method. While you can use metaprogramming to alter the singleton class from an instance this is most likely not what you want.

Comment: I'm not confused about when code gets run - I'm looking to see if an alternate method of register a one off callback exists. In the example I don't want to run the callback after every commit (which is what your code does) - I just want to run if the `verify` method gets run. I understand I can re-write the after_commit slightly to use the if syntax (and wrap it in a proc) - but that is still the same ugly syntax. I'll add a temporary answer via a concern that I came up with for the interim - still looking for a better solution...

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you need to verify a user after create.

```
after_commit :run_sidekiq_job, on: :create
after_commit :run_sidekiq_job, on: [:create, :update] // if you want on update as well.
```

This will ensure that your job will run only after a commit to db.

Then define your job that has to be performed.

```
def run_sidekiq_job
  ---------------
  ---------------
end
```

Hope it helps you :)